# Access source generated class property/method in main code MSVS 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, sourcegenerators

I created my first source generator (`ISourceGenerator`) with public property and public method.

Let this class be like this:

```
public partial class MyClass1 // Manually written code
{
}

public partial class MyClass1 //Source Generated code
{
    public string GeneratedProperty { get; set; }
    public string GeneratedMethod() => "lala";
}
```

Both of these classes are located in the same namespace (for example, `MyNamespace` - it doesn't matter really).

So, I'm trying this:

```
var myClass = new MyClass1(); // Correct
Console.WriteLine(myClass.GeneratedMethod()); //Wrong, "MyClass1 doesn't contain definition for GeneratedMethod..."
```

When I say MSVS generate sources as files in the concrete directory, I have the code above working well.

So, I want to have an ability to use generated code "on fly" when I write code without generation source files each time manually. Also earlier manually generated source files are not deleted when I'm generating new source files.
Is it possible?

Thank you.

UPD. I have this message from Visual Studio:
"Warning    CS8032  An instance of analyzer Generators.Factory.AbstractFactoryGenerator cannot be created from ...\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\SourceGeneratorsLibrary.dll: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."
Maybe this significant?

UPD2. https://pastebin.com/qtvrugu3  - this is my Source Generator code. Pls, don't blame me, It's just my first steps.

Comment: see: [Source Generators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview).

Comment: Your generator should already be running in the IDE; if you're not seeing that then something might be broken.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski unfortunatelly, I don't know the reason. I've checked all possible sources/articles (also the link above), tried all possible combination of csproj parameters, but still have "This generator is not generating files" message in my Dependencies. Can it be connected with preview features like "Generic attributes"?

Comment: If you could share all of your code in a github repo, that would be useful. According to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/ you must put your source generators into their own project and then reference them in another project. It sounds like you might be doing that, but it's hard to know for sure without the source code (including .csproj files)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, programming is case sensitive, well at least C# so myClass() is different from MyClass(). also hence you are using the `string` data type, try casting it as string via

> Convert.ToString(MyClass1().GeneratedMethod());

or

> MyClass1().GeneratedMethod().ToString();

hope this answers you question.

Comment: The `myClass` reference is a variable that the instance of `MyClass1` is assigned to; the variable name is arbitrary, so the casing is fine. Also, `Object` has a `ToString()` method which will, by default, output the type name and will be executed when calling `WriteLine()`; that value may not be especially _useful_ if the data type doesn’t override `ToString()` to output a more meaningful value, but it will still write _a_ value. Regardless, if it were a type conversion issue, the OP would be getting a different error. In other words, this answer doesn’t address the OP’s issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have developed your analyzer but not actually referenced it from a project?

To use your analyzer you simply add it as as project reference, but make sure it's marked up as an analyzer in the .csproj file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
     <ProjectReference Include="MyGenerator\MyGenerator.csproj" OutputItemType="Analyzer" ReferenceOutputAssembly="false" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Or something like that, adjusted to your solution.